# URL Rewrite Module messing with $_GET variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've established a semi-working .htaccess file which alters this link:

```
localhost/profile.php?id=6
```

to this:

```
localhost/profile/6
```

However, this is adding .php to the end of my $_GET variables. I'm not very familiar with rewrite modules, .htaccess etc but this is very annoying. Couldn't find anything on the internet about it, if there is a different way to do it or fix it I would greatly appreciate any input.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) profile.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you put what you have for the .htaccess rules.

Comment: Meant to include it, sorry. Updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restricting to only numbers:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(\d*) profile.php?id=$1
```

Or exclude `.`, if the ID is not certainly numeric:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^.]*) profile.php?id=$1
```